# Show all field values in Drupal through a View

Tags: views, entities, nodes

I have a field named "Programs" in my content type. It's a Multi-select List. With every new node, I select one or more Programs through the multi-select list.

Now I am hoping to show all of these "selected" values of the field Programs, that I selected in all the nodes I created.

### As an example, if these are the list values in the field "Programs"

- Chemical Engg.
- Computer Sc.
- Arts
- Electrical Engg.
- Info. Systems

### and if I created (let's say) 5 nodes, in which I selected these fields in the following manner:-

- Info. Systems (Node 1)
- Arts, Electrical Engg. (Node 2)
- Info. Systems (Node 3)
- Computer Sc., Arts, Info. Systems (Node 4)
- Arts (Node 5)

Now, my question is how to show these "selected" Field values through a view?

Notice, I wrote selected as I only want to show the field values which have been selected in the node.

So, my view would show the following values (notice Chemical Engg. is not here as no node selected it.):-

- Computer Sc.
- Arts
- Electrical Engg.
- Info. Systems

Thanks.

### Update

I created a view that displays the nodes of my content type and added the field 'Programs' to it, but the only problem is that it shows comma separated programs if I selected more than one programs with a specific node. I just need it to show one program, as the user can select the programs and see all nodes associated with it.

Comment: Why can't you simply create a new view that displays the nodes of your content type and add the field 'Programs' to it? Doesn't that work?

Comment: I did that, but the only problem is that it shows comma seperated programs if I selected more than one programs with a specific node. I just need it to show one program, as the user can select the programs and see all nodes associated with it.

Comment: You should mention that in your question too.

Comment: So, if I understand your update, you essentially want a drop-down list with all of the available options. A user selects one, and then the view shows only those nodes that had the same selection (selecting Arts brings up every node that has a *selection* of Arts)?

Comment: Yes sir :). This is it. P.S. It can just be a normal ul,li list and doesn't have to be a dropdown list.